# Reg - Activating Application while using Device Replay Method

Tags: qtp

I need to pass keystrokes and string into an Edit box which has an event handeler (once value entered in edit box, an Web Button will get enabled.

In the above scenario am using Device replay method. And below is my code. The Problem is am not able to activate my browser with Device replay object. And hence sent key are sent to Application properly.

Could anyone help me on this.

```
Set Obj = CreateObject ("Mercury.DeviceReplay")
Systemutil.Run "D:\QTP Training\Example Form\Dynamic_1.html"
Browser("Browser").Page("Page").Sync
For i=1 to 12
Obj.PressKey(09)
Next
Obj.SendString "Lakshman"
Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebButton("Type and enable me").Click
Browser("Browser").Dialog("Message from webpage").WinButton("OK").Click
```

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the `WebEdit` object with `DeviceReplay`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried the same method but the other issue which am getting is: the ASCII code of horizontal tab is 09 but when I use this am not able to navigate to other fields but instead it prints '8' in the same Text box. Any reason why this ascii code '09' for Tab is not working?

Comment: Have you tried `9` instead of `09`? I'm not sure about VBScript but in most languages a leading `0` means its an octal number and `9` isn't an octal number.

Comment: I tried both '09' and '9' with and without double quotes. But both of them entered character '8' in edit box instead of navigating to the other edit box.

Answer (score 0):

QTP defines a constant called `micTab` for typing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. Try that instead of `09`

Comment: No, this didn't work, giving micTab gives a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 0):

I have found success in some unusual situations where some QTP functions are not supported by some applications by using sendkeys method.

Try `Obj.SendKeys "{9}"`

Comment: Thank you, SendKeys method works by creating wscript.shell object. But was more curious on my DeviceReplay object method didn't work.